Where can you learn the Russian language for free in Russia?
My family will be moving to Russia in a few months. We don't know where yet. Though we have no interest in Moscow or St. Petersburg, if that helps. Where I live in Albania, local language courses cost a year's salary, per month. So no one can afford them. In the USA, and Japan, you can learn for free. Pretty sure EU nations have free courses too.
So does Russia have something like this? Aren't all universities free anyways? Thank you!

I highly doubt that any free courses of good quality exist. There might be some state program targeting migrants, but the quality will be appalling. However, a private course should not cost much. I do not know any specific examples, but a ballpark estimate (based on foreign language courses) will be below 10-20 thousand rubles per month, which is much less than the average salary in Russia.

In what part of Russia will you live and (sorry for a personal question) what you will be doing for living? 10k rubles is a very low salary in Russia. The official statistics says (https://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_326052/) that the average salary in 2024 is above 80k rubles. This might be inflated by Moscow and other top-salary cities, but a typical Auchan cashier will earn above 30k in large cities. I believe that delivery couriers earn above 30k, and so on.

No one gets average income. Most jobs pay 10,000-20,000 a month. Not sure where we will live yet. Just likely not Moscow or St. Petersburg (I mentioned that). Where we live will mostly be determined where we can find work, housing, and so on. lol No one gets 80,000 a month. The Russian language resources are great! That is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you everyone. And if anyone has any other advice? I sure don't want to be in the snow with 10 kids and babies! Thank you!

I know many people who earn more than 100k. Where do you get the idea that "most jobs pay 10,000-20,000 a month" from? (Not to mention that with your level of English, after you get a bit of grasp of Russian, you'll most probably be able to privately tutor Russia school student in English, earning at least 500 rubles per hour...)


Though we have no interest in Moscow or St. Petersburg, if that helps.

That doesn't help, that's a huge downside. If there are such courses anywhere, they're in the capitals. Universities in Russia tend to have free places for many programs, but РКИ (Russian as a foreign language) isn't typically among them.
Also,

My family will be moving to Russia in a few months.

Is it too late to reconsider moving to a place that is corrupt, authoritarian and suspicious of European foreigners?

Russia is the only country in the world that allows Americans in. It is also the only country that has family values. On top of this, it has the highest wages, the lowest cost of living, and everything is free. Not only do we have no options, but this is the best option in the world!

@Isabella, as someone who had to escape this supposed paradize, I assure you it doesn't fit that description on most counts.
